# Can't onchange call JS function in reg.cgi using .tmpl

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl, cgi

I work on a site. This site has a registration page reg.cgi that uses a registration.tmpl template. I included some javascript in the registration.tmpl . The javascript code has a simple function that needs to be called every time the user
changes the select option (onchange="myCoolFunction()") but it won't trigger. I think it's because of Perl. Maybe I need to change the reg.cgi or am I wrong.

In the chrome Console there is one error:

- Uncaught ReferenceError: myCoolFunction() is not defined

The definition is:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  function myCoolFunction() {
        if ($("#payment_card").val() == '00') {
            $('input[name="cvv2"]').prop('disabled',true);
        }
        if ($("#payment_card").val() == 'VI') {
            $('input[name="cvv2"]').val("");
            $('input[name="cvv2"]').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('input[name="cvv2"]').attr('maxlength','3');
        }
        if ($("#payment_card").val() == 'AM') {
            $('input[name="cvv2"]').val("");
            $('input[name="cvv2"]').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('input[name="cvv2"]').attr('maxlength','4');
        }
  };
}
);
```

And the call is:

```
<select id="payment_card" onchange="myCoolFunction()">
  <option value="00"></option>
  <option value="VI">VISA, MC</option>
  <option value="AM">AMEX</option>
</select>
```

I tested the plain javascript + HTML locally and there were no errors. It worked, but online on the server with the cgi it won't work.
If someone has some experience with .cgi + tmpl + javascript it would be great to 
help or advise me. Is it right to include javacript in a .tmpl what is used in a .cgi?
Thank You.

Comment: Looks like there's a syntax error in your function. Could you show it's definition? Also, how are you including the script in the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using window.onload and removed document.ready, below the function definition:
`window.onload = function(){myCoolFunction()};`

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error in Chrome after pasting code copied from jsfiddle. I think you are facing the same issue.

If you select all the code from a panel in jsfiddle and paste it into Notepad++, you should be able to see the problem character as a question mark "?" at the very end of your code. Delete this question mark, then copy and paste the code from Notepad++ and the problem should be gone.

Regarding `myCoolFunction() is not defined`. Please share your code so that we can see where are you doing wrong.

**Edit:** (based on your response that why doesn't it work on jsFiddle)

JSFiddle wraps your javascript code in the onLoad call of the page by default so myFunction is defined only in that function's scope. Change to No wrap - in  and your code will run as expected. See this, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/chankeypathak/SB3gd/2/

Comment: I haven't used jsfiddle for that. Everything I test I do locally with XAMPP. But I Inserted on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kingSlayer/SB3gd/1/) and it wont' work on jsfiddle either. Why does it work on my XAMPP.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but on the server there is still: **myCoolFunction() is not defined**